# Class Extending MY_Controller in "libraries" folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have created a `MY_Controller` Class that extends `CI_COntroller` inside the application/core folder.

Now what i want is to create another class that will extend the `MY_Controller` class but it is inside the `application/libraries`

```
class Myclass extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

     }

}
```

but when i load this class this is the result:

```
Unable to locate the specified class: Cache.php
```

Am I correct in saving Myclass.php inside the `application/libraries` ?
Is there any other way in extending `CI_Controller` ?
thank you sir newbie in `codeigniter 3.0.0`

Comment: You could include the Core file? `include APPPATH "core/MY_Controller.php";` at the top of your library file?

Comment: whenever you try to extend a library from a core controller class you have a pretty serious design problem - whats the purpose for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in extending MY_Controller in the application/libraries folder. However, you should create your MY_Controller extension of CI_Controller in the application/controllers folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Associative Controller call `MY_Controller`. You Need to use `CI_Controller`. You can change you controller name `Myclass` as your wish. But controller file name should be `myclass.php`.

```
class Myclass extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

     }
}
```

**Example of Usage**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Myclass extends CI_Controller
{
    public function  __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //load libraries and model which you use inside your controller.  

    }
}
```